# How do I measure the benefits of unit testing?

Tags: unit-testing, metrics

I'm in the process of pushing my company towards having unit tests as a major part of the development cycle.  I've gotten the testing framework working with our MVC framework, and multiple members of the team are now writing unit tests.  I'm at the point, though, where there's work that needs to be done to improve our hourly build, the ease of figuring out what fixtures you need to use, adding functionality to the mock object generator, etc., etc., and I want to be able to make the case for this work to management.  In addition, I'd like us to allocate time to write unit tests for the most critical pieces of existing code, and I just don't see that happening without a more specific case than "everyone knows unit tests are good".

How do you quantify the positive impact of (comprehensive and reliable) unit tests on your projects?  I can certainly look at the number and severity of bugs filed and correlate it with our increases in code coverage, but that's a rather weak metric.

Comment: This might be better-suited for the Programmers site.

Comment: It may be a weak metric, but from a business perspective it's the *only* metric: does the investment in better testing reduce the cost of development (including QA). If you track support costs, that's another possibility, but there are significant lags there.

Comment: Anon: this is valuable, but *how* do I measure whether the investment in better testing reduces the cost of development?  Presenting a correlation is better than nothing, but I'm trying to find a more convincing way than just "we put in a bunch of work on unit tests, and after some time our team's throughput increased".

Comment: Assuming that you have an ongoing development process, and track bugs, you can make statements like "For projects that don't have unit tests, we see approximately 50 bugs reported by QA per project-month; where we require 70% coverage on new code, we see approximately 20 bugs reported per project month." Then it comes down to the cost of test development versus the cost of QA and bugfixes. Plus intangibles such as delaying the project.

Comment: That still leaves the bootstrap problem: how do you get that first project to use unit tests. The answer there is to find a business sponsor who's willing to look at outside teams' results and also willing to add the extra up-front time. That can be hard, no doubt, but I believe your ability to do that is directly related to your ability to actually get a test-infected culture going.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/) is a company that makes a very interesting code inspection tool, they actually try to [measure technical debt](http://www.sonarsource.org/evaluate-your-technical-debt-with-sonar/) programaticaly, which correlates untested code and developer price per hour.

Answer (score 1):

Quantification of test-quality is very difficult.

I see code-coverage only as guidance not as test-quality metric. You can literally write test of 100% code-coverage without testing anything (e.g. no asserts are used at all). Also have a look at my [blog-post](http://www.aldana-online.de/2010/11/14/top-4-software-metrics-antipatterns/) where I warn against metric-pitfalls.

The only sensible quantitative metric I know of and which counts for business is really reduced effort of bug-fixes in production-code. Also reduced bug-severity. Still it is very difficult to isolate that unit-tests are the only source of this success (it could also be improvement of process or communication).

Generally I would focus on the qualitative approach:

- Do developers feel more comfortable changing code (because tests are a trustworthy safety net)?
- When bugs occur in production analysis really shows that it was untested code (vice versa a minor conlusion that it wouldn't have occurred if there had been unit test)